# Windows 8 XAML ListView Header not same size

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8.1

Currently having an issue where the header of my ListView is larger than my ListView Items, so the header doesn't line up properly. I could use a margin on the header as a hack to fix it, but surely there's a proper way to fix this?

[image: Why is the header bigger??]

```
<DataTemplate  x:Key="HeaderTemplate" >
    <Grid Height="36" Background="#99999999" Margin="0,0,5,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Uid="Name" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Project" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
        <TextBlock x:Uid="Qty" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Qty" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
        <TextBlock x:Uid="SubTotal" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Sub Total" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
        <TextBlock x:Uid="Total" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Total" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

// ...

<ListView x:Name="CartGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding CartItmes}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"
    Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SimpleListViewItemStyle}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="auto" Margin="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding Qty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Text="{Binding SubTotal, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding Total, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: try by setting the Width property of the template grid.

Comment: template grid? do you mean the grid.ColumnDefinitons?

Comment: No , i mean it for <DataTemplate  x:Key="HeaderTemplate" >
    <Grid Height="36" Background="#99999999" Margin="0,0,5,0" Width="400">

Comment: The width is somwhat correct already, the issue is that the rows are automatically shrink slightly (width) to format to cater for things like the scrollbar. I have temporarily just done the dirty manual margin adjustment so that it doesn't look wrong. But I would say (for future readers) unless sombody has a proper way of doing so, I would say that the best solution is to include the header as the first row of the ListView and through Conditions disable it's selectable and apply a special style to it to make it look as if it's not a part of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your ListView definition

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Note that for (full) Windows 8.1 there was a breaking change. Now the ListView must have a VirtualizingStackPanel for its ItemsPanel (See some of the later comments here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8d4f7b3-93a8-4f17-9679-8b700b8d02e6/how-to-adjust-the-width-of-group-header-in-listview-to-stretch-full-width?forum=winappswithcsharp)